# Where were the rockets of "El Macho" headed?

Tags: despicable-me

In *Despicable Me 2*, there were 6 rockets filled with evil minions in El Macho's headquarters and they were headed to different cities. I could read only one of them and it was Paris. Do you know the rest of them? I'm interested in what countries El Macho hated most :)

Answer (score 6):

There are in fact **ten** rockets in total. The names that can be read on the sides of the rockets are;

- **New York**
- **Paris**
- **Hoboken**
- **Moscow**
- **Sydney**

and

- **Tok**(yo, presumably)

[image: Despicable Me Rockets]

The [Despicable me](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Earth) wikia also lists

- **Rio de Janeiro**

and

- **Beijing**

although this information seems to be unsourced.

Comment: If I were El Macho, I'd make only eight rockets, and set them to Rome, New York, Sydney, Cairo, London, Paris, Moscow, and Washington DC.

Comment: @b_jonas - You seem to have completely ignored South America and the Far East. That represents some 40% of the world's population.

Comment: when the Grand Intellect, controlling the Vorticons, has chosen those cities as targets for the Tantalus ray, he probably had his reasons.  Unless El Macho thinks he's either smarter than the Grand Intellect, or knows more than him about the secret defenses of Earth, it's better to assume they're suitable targets.  The Grand Intellect grew up on Earth, and this wasn't his first time working as a criminal mastermind.